# WSO2CEP siddhi unable to parse substr extension function in event execution plan

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have tried to get the ExectuionPlanRuntime by the SiddhiManger as below

```
public static ExecutionPlanRuntime getExecutionPlanRuntime(String plan) {
        return new SiddhiManager().createExecutionPlanRuntime(plan);
}
```

The String plan has an expression which extracts a value by the `str:substr` WSO2CEP function extension as below

```
define stream PROBE_DATA(speed string);
from PROBE_DATA[ convert(str:substr(speed, '(\d*)' ), 'int') > 30]
insert into ostream;
```

But I have got the ExecutionPlanValidationException says **substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute in execution plan**

```
org.wso2.siddhi.query.api.exception.ExecutionPlanValidationException: substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute in execution plan "ce1873e8-9247-4d16-a8ee-f9146e1e8c79"
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.parse(ExecutionPlanParser.java:127) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:51) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:59) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.test.utils.SiddhiUtils.getExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiUtils.java:82) ~[SiddhiUtils.class:na]
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanCreationException: substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:111) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.parse(ExecutionPlanParser.java:117) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanCreationException: substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:292) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:319) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:123) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SingleInputStreamParser.generateProcessor(SingleInputStreamParser.java:129) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SingleInputStreamParser.parseInputStream(SingleInputStreamParser.java:86) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.InputStreamParser.parse(InputStreamParser.java:51) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:64) ~[siddhi-core-3.0.2.jar:na]
    ... 111 common frames omitted
```

However, the same ExecutionPlan is valid by the WSO2CEP console as below image shows.

[image]

The following are my siddhi pom dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-core</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.log4j.wso2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler.wso2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-query-api</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.log4j.wso2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-query-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.log4j.wso2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The WSO2CEP server is version 4.0.0 and the siddhi lib it uses is version 3.0.2, but I have tried version 3.0.2, 3.0.3 and the latest one version 3.1.2 for my app client, all of them are not help and got the same exception as above.

Did I miss something to setup for my app client can recognize the siddhi function extension?

Answer (score 2):

`substr` is a function which returns an attribute. Therefore, it cannot be applied within the `from` statement; rather it has to be applied within the `select` statement. Please see an example query below:

```
from inputStream 
select symbol, str:substr(symbol, 4) as substring  
insert into outputStream;
```